# Alarm Manager Does Not Execute Repeatedly

Tags: java, android, service, alarm

I'm working on a group project for a class I'm taking and we cannot seem to figure out why our Alarm Manager does not fire intents repeatedly. We've picked through the source code from top to bottom and cannot seem to isolate the source of this issue.

Can anyone recommend a fix? (or perhaps a starting point?)

// Start service using AlarmManager

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Rules.this, LMW.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Rules.this, 0, intent,
            0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            7 * 1000, pintent);


    // Start 2nd service using AlarmManager
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Rules.this, KillTimer.class);
    PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0, intent2,
            0);
    AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            120 * 1000, pintent2); // here
```

Source:

```
public class AlarmManager extends ListActivity {


    TextView empty;
    TextView empty2;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;

    public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private List<ParseObject> todos;
    private Dialog progressDialog;

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Override this method to do custom remote calls
        public void setVisibility() {
               empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

        }
        protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Gets the current list of todos in sorted order
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
            try {
                todos = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return;
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {  
                   }});
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ToDoListActivity.this, "",
                    "Loading...", true);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Put the list of todos into the list view
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ToDoListActivity.this,
                    R.layout.todo_row);
            for (ParseObject todo : todos) {
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataI"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataO"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataRSSI"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataSSID"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataTIME"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataRESTRICTED"));
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_new);

            empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    private void createTodo() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateTodo.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String DataI = extras.getString("DataI");
                    String DataO = extras.getString("DataO");
                    String DataRSSI = extras.getString("DataRSSI");
                    String DataSSID = extras.getString("DataSSID");
                    String DataTIME = extras.getString("DataTIME");
                    String DataRESTRICTED = extras.getString("DataRESTRICTED");
                    ParseObject todo = new ParseObject("Todo");
                    todo.put("DataI", DataI);
                    todo.put("DataO", DataO);
                    todo.put("DataRSSI", DataRSSI);
                    todo.put("DataSSID", DataSSID);
                    todo.put("DataTIME", DataTIME);
                    todo.put("DataRESTRICTED", DataRESTRICTED);
                    try { todo.save(); } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }

                    super.doInBackground();
                    return;
                }
            }.execute();
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
            // Edit the remote object
            final ParseObject todo;
            todo = todos.get(extras.getInt("position"));
            todo.put("DataI", extras.getString("DataI"));
            todo.put("DataO", extras.getString("DataO"));
            todo.put("DataRSSI", extras.getString("DataRSSI"));
            todo.put("DataSSID", extras.getString("DataSSID"));
            todo.put("DataTIME", extras.getString("DataTIME"));
            todo.put("DataRESTRICTED", extras.getString("DataRESTRICTED"));

            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        todo.save();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                    super.doInBackground();
                    return;
                }
            }.execute();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            // Delete the remote object
            final ParseObject todo = todos.get(info.position);


            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        todo.delete();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                    super.doInBackground();
                    return;
                }
            }.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createTodo();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateTodo.class);

        i.putExtra("DataI", todos.get(position).getString("DataI").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataO", todos.get(position).getString("DataO").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataRSSI", todos.get(position).getString("DataRSSI").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataSSID", todos.get(position).getString("DataSSID").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataTIME", todos.get(position).getString("DataTIME").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataRESTRICTED", todos.get(position).getString("DataRESTRICTED").toString());
        i.putExtra("position", position);


        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

}
```

Service Class

```
public class LMW extends Service {
        String Watchdog = "Watchdog";   
        String Dirty1 = "playboy";
        String Dirty2 = "penthouse";
        String Dirty3 = "pornhub";
        String Dirty4 = "thepiratebay";
        String Dirty5 = "vimeo";
        String Dirty6 = "wired";
        String Dirty7 = "limewire";
        String Dirty8 = "whitehouse";
        String Dirty9 = "hackaday";
        String Dirty10 = "slashdot";
      Long mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
      Long  mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Watchdog Running!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Long.toString(mStartTX);
    Long.toString(mStartRX);
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("DataO", String.valueOf(mStartTX));
    testObject.put("DataI", String.valueOf(mStartRX));

    testObject.saveInBackground();                String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                String urls = "";
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String url1 = null;
                String url2 = null;
                do {
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
                Log.i(Watchdog, url);
                 if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1) || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2) || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3) || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)  || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)  || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)  || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)  || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)  || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)  || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10))
                 {
                     Intent intent2 = new Intent(LMW.this, Warning.class);
                     intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                     startActivity(intent2);
                     break;
                 }          } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
    }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
}}
```

Activity Class:

```
public class Timer extends Activity {

    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.killtimer);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KillWifi Running!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
      wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId );
      wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

  }}
```

Comment: Holy code, Batman!!! How about starting with where you set the alarms?

Comment: Updated : ) [sorry about that!]

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem and perhaps it applies to you (hard to tell since the code you supplied is pretty hard to navigate).

My issue was that applying multiple intents to the manager that evaluated as equal overrode the previous applications of that intent.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent) for what I mean by equivalence.
As an example, I had a schedule that used the URI domy://thing, with extras that varied over each intent (I need to fire the same action with different arguments each time).  Extras don't count in equivalence, so my alarms were getting overwritten by each other.

To get around this, I stored a queue of my alarms in a separate file and when one fired, popped the next off the top and put that in the manager.  Maybe that'll help you.

UPDATE: 
No examples publicly visible, but try this (Trigger is a simple object containing a URI and a time it needs to be fired, scheduleDb is a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper):

```
  /**
   * Pops the next trigger off the queue, adds it to the alarm manager, and
   * stores it in the DB in case we need to cancel it later.
   */
  private void scheduleNextTrigger() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Popping next trigger off queue");
    Optional<Trigger> nextTrigger = scheduleDb.getNextTrigger();

    if (!nextTrigger.isPresent()) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Trigger queue is empty");
      return;
    }
    Trigger trigger = nextTrigger.get();
    Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling new trigger " + trigger);
    PendingIntent operation = createPendingIntent(trigger);
    long timestamp = trigger.getTimestamp();

    // Ensure the next item is in the future
    if (timestamp > clock.currentTimeMillis()) {
      Log.v(TAG, "Found valid trigger: " + trigger);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timestamp, operation);
    }
    scheduleDb.setScheduledTrigger(trigger);
  }

  private PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Trigger trigger) {
    // AlarmManager allows only one instance of each URI, and seems to randomly
    // delete bundled URI extras, so we'll encode the triggered URI and place it
    // on a constant stem
    Uri triggerUri = Uri.parse(TRIGGER_URI + "?" + Uri.encode(trigger.getUri()));

    Intent triggerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, triggerUri);
    triggerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    Log.d(TAG, "Created trigger intent " + triggerIntent);

    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, triggerIntent, 0);

    return operation;
  }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Can you point me towards an example of how this can be implemented? (I really need to get this issue resolved)

Comment: I've put what I can in the answer.

Comment: Were you able to make use of this info? If so I recommend you accept one or other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the links, It helped me a lot.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/schedule-repeating-alarm.html